# A Star, Updating G Cost for Nodes

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I have a somewhat working A* algorithm here. It can find a path to the destination, however, it is unable to update its path if a better one becomes available.

for example:

```
s = start
e = end
x = wall
. = path
```

it is doing this:

```
       x
s......x   e
      .x  .
      .x .
      .x.
       .
```

and I want it to do this:

```
       x
s .    x   e
   .   x  .
    .  x .
     . x.
       .
```

What I need is for the tiles(nodes) to change their parent node to one with a lower G - cost if it is available. The struggle in implementing this is real.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Cheers

```
    map = [

['w','w','w','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','w','w','w'],

]

""" make copy of dict in the function! """
tile_data = {}

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, pos, char):

        self.pos = pos
        self.char = char
        self.parent = None

        self.H = 0
        self.G = float('inf')
        self.F = 0

#Gen Tiles
for y in range(len(map)):
    for x in range(len(map[0])):
        char = map[y][x]
        tile = Tile((x,y), char)
        tile_data[(x,y)] = tile

def a_star(start, end, map):

    unchecked_tiles = []
    checked_tiles = []

    # set start position
    tile_data[start].parent = None
    tile_data[start].pos = start
    tile_data[start].G = 0
    unchecked_tiles.append(tile_data[start])

    while unchecked_tiles:

        #Get the tile with lowest F score
        current_tile = min(unchecked_tiles, key=lambda tile: tile.F)

        #move tile to checked list
        checked_tiles.append(current_tile)
        unchecked_tiles.remove(current_tile)

        # If the End is found return the path of parent tiles
        if current_tile.pos == end:
            path = []
            while current_tile.parent is not None:
                path.append(current_tile.pos)
                # Sets current tile to parent tile
                current_tile = current_tile.parent

            for tile in path:
                print(tile, ": F = ", tile_data[tile].F, ": G = ", tile_data[tile].G, ": H = ", tile_data[tile].H)

            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Gets valid neighbors for current tile
        neighbors = []
        for dir in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]:
            #get tile pos
            neighbor = (current_tile.pos[0] + dir[0], current_tile.pos[1] + dir[1])

            #check if tile on map and is valid
            if 0 <= neighbor[0] < len(map[0]) and 0 <= neighbor[1] < len(map) and tile_data[neighbor].char == 'w' and tile_data[neighbor] not in checked_tiles:

                # Set parent for neighbors
                tile_data[neighbor].parent = current_tile

                # Add neighbor to lists
                unchecked_tiles.append(tile_data[neighbor])
                neighbors.append(neighbor)

        for neighbor in neighbors:
            # Set G cost (14 for diagonal, 10 for othogonal move + parent.G cost)

            if tile_data[neighbor].pos[0] == current_tile.pos[0] or tile_data[neighbor].pos[1] == current_tile.pos[1]:
                tile_data[neighbor].G = 10 + current_tile.G
            else:                           
                tile_data[neighbor].G = 14 + current_tile.G
            
            if tile_data[neighbor].G < current_tile.G:
                current_tile.parent = tile_data[neighbor].parent

            # Set H cost (a**2 + b**2 = c**2)
            tile_data[neighbor].H = ((neighbor[0] - end[0]) ** 2) + ((neighbor[1] - end[1]) ** 2)

            # Set F cost (G + H)
            tile_data[neighbor].F = tile_data[neighbor].H + tile_data[neighbor].G

    print('finished')

a_star((0,2),(4,2),map)
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "if a better one becomes available"? The algorithm will always find the shortest path. Is the graph updated after the search?

Comment: A "better one" is a tile/node with a shorter distance to the start/ G-score. Sorry, should have clarrified.

Comment: Right but the question is what changed that would result in a shorter distance or even a better G score. Once you run an A* search the algorithm necessarily explores all nodes in the graph. The best possible G score is then calculated to obtain the shortest distance. If a shorter path is possible than something has gone wrong. If you change the graph or the start/end you must recaculate the G score.

Comment: If I understand a star correctly, what changes is the node discovering a neighboring tile that has a lower g score than itself. It then uses that tile instead when finding the path. For example, if it runs into a wall it will find a diagonal path to the end of the wall instead of making an 'L'  shape.

Comment: What you're probably strugging with most right now is building the final destination path from start to end. The edge case you might be alluding to is that of a early bail. This is the rare case where the algorithm finds the first possible path to the end node without completing all other possible paths that may or may not exist, which may be more optimal. There are ways optimize this problem whether rerunning the algorithm until all nodes in the graph are exhausted or using something such [bounded relaxation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#:~:text=Bounded-,relaxation).

Comment: Additionally [here is a reference implementation and blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170112174256/http://phpden.info/A*-path-finding-algorithm) I wrote a while back that may be of some benefit to you. Hope that helps nudge you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was moving duplicate neighbors to "unchecked" tiles with incorrect G-costs. Anyhow here is a working A* algorithm :)

'''

```
map = [

['w','w','w','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','x','w','w'],
['w','w','w','w','w'],

]

""" make copy of dict in the function! """
tile_data = {}

class Tile:
    def __init__(self, pos, char):

        self.pos = pos
        self.char = char
        self.parent = None

        self.H = 0
        self.G = 0
        self.F = 0

#Gen Tiles
for y in range(len(map)):
    for x in range(len(map[0])):
        char = map[y][x]
        tile = Tile((x,y), char)
        tile_data[(x,y)] = tile

def a_star(start, end, map):

    unchecked_tiles = []
    checked_tiles = []

    # set start position
    tile_data[start].parent = None
    tile_data[start].pos = start
    tile_data[start].G = 0
    unchecked_tiles.append(tile_data[start])

    while unchecked_tiles:

        #Get the tile with lowest F score
        current_tile = min(unchecked_tiles, key=lambda tile: tile.F)

        #move tile to checked list
        checked_tiles.append(current_tile)
        unchecked_tiles.remove(current_tile)

        # If the End is found return the path of parent tiles
        if current_tile.pos == end:
            path = []
            while current_tile.parent is not None:
                path.append(current_tile.pos)
                # Sets current tile to parent tile
                current_tile = current_tile.parent

            for tile in path:
                print(tile, ": F = ", tile_data[tile].F, ": G = ", tile_data[tile].G, ": H = ", tile_data[tile].H)

            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Gets valid neighbors for current tile
        neighbors = []
        for dir in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]:
            #get tile pos
            neighbor = (current_tile.pos[0] + dir[0], current_tile.pos[1] + dir[1])

            #check if tile on map and is valid
            if 0 <= neighbor[0] < len(map[0]) and 0 <= neighbor[1] < len(map) and tile_data[neighbor].char == 'w' and tile_data[neighbor] not in checked_tiles:

                if tile_data[neighbor] not in unchecked_tiles:
                    # Add neighbor to lists
                    unchecked_tiles.append(tile_data[neighbor])
                    neighbors.append(neighbor)

                    # Set parent for neighbors
                    tile_data[neighbor].parent = current_tile

        for neighbor in neighbors:
            # Set G cost (14 for diagonal, 10 for othogonal move + parent.G cost)

            if tile_data[neighbor].pos[0] == current_tile.pos[0] or tile_data[neighbor].pos[1] == current_tile.pos[1]:
                tile_data[neighbor].G = 10 + current_tile.G
            else:                           
                tile_data[neighbor].G = 14 + current_tile.G
            
            if tile_data[neighbor].G < current_tile.G:
                current_tile.parent = tile_data[neighbor].parent
                if tile_data[neighbor].pos[0] == current_tile.pos[0] or tile_data[neighbor].pos[1] == current_tile.pos[1]:
                    current_tile.G = tile_data[neighbor].G + 10
                else:
                    current_tile.G = tile_data[neighbor].G + 14

            # Set H cost (a**2 + b**2 = c**2)
            tile_data[neighbor].H = ((neighbor[0] - end[0]) ** 2) + ((neighbor[1] - end[1]) ** 2)

            # Set F cost (G + H)
            tile_data[neighbor].F = tile_data[neighbor].H + tile_data[neighbor].G

    print('finished')

a_star((0,2),(4,2),map)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

```
def aStarSearch(problem: SearchProblem, heuristic=None):
    """Search the node that has the lowest combined cost and heuristic first."""
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    class Node:  
      def __init__(self, state, parent=None):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(state=%s, g=%s, h=%s, f=%s)" % (self.state, self.g, self.h, self.f)

    print("There is A* start",problem.getStartState())
    start=problem.getStartState()
    openSet=[]
    closeSet=[]
    openSet.append(start)
    while (openSet):
        current=openSet.pop(0)
        print("current:",current)
        if problem.isGoalState(current):
            path = reconstruct_path(curren)
            return path
        closeSet.append(current)
        print("In Close set we add current value",current)
        successors=problem.getSuccessors(current)
        print("There we add s",successors)
        for successor in successors:
            if successor in closeSet:
                continue
            successor_node=Node(successor,current)
            successor_node.g= current.g + cost_to_move(current.state, successor)
            successor_node.h = heuristic(successor, start)
            successor_node.f = successor_node.g + successor_node.h
            print("successor.g we have:",successor.g)
            if successor_node in open_list and successor_node.f >= open_list[open_list.index(successor_node)].f:
                continue
            open_list.append(successor_node)
 #In this i still face some issue like Error Like:
successor_node.g= current.g + cost_to_move(current.state, successor)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'g'
​
```